# Non-linear fitting with weighted errorbars - Minimizer/scipy.curve_fit/model.fit

Tags: python, lmfit

I am working on a Python fitting code for Michaelies-Menten, a non-linear equation, able to include weighted errorbars. At the moment I have tried using `Minimizer` and `model.fit` from `lmfit`. Though `Minimizer` does not include weighted errorbars and `model.fit` seems to be less statistical than `Minimizer`.
Is there a way to include weighted errorbars in `Minimizer`?
Would `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` be a better way to fit this code?
Or is there another fitting program that would be better?

My code is below

```
def michealies_menten(path, conc, substrate):
os.chdir(path)
h = open('average_STD_data.dat', 'r')
f = open('concentration.dat', 'r')

x = []
y = []
std = []
std_1 = []

for line in h:
    line = line.split(',')
    y.append(line[0])
    std.append(line[1])

for line in f:
    x = line.split(',')

for i in range(len(std)):
    new = 1.0/(float(std[i])**2.0)
    std_1.append(float(new))

std.insert(0, '0')
std_1.insert(0, '0')
x.insert(0, '0')
y.insert(0, '0')
y=map(float,y)
x=map(float,x)
std=map(float,std)
std_1=map(float,std_1)

x=np.array(x)
y=np.array(y)
std_1=np.array(std_1)

####Model.fit code:
def my_model(x, Vmax, Km):
    return Vmax * x / (Km + x)
gmodel = Model(my_model)
result = gmodel.fit(y, x=x, Vmax=4000.0, Km=3.0, weights=std_1)
print result.fit_report()
Vmax_1=result.params['Vmax'].value
Km_1=result.params['Km'].value

model = (Vmax_1*x/(Km_1+x))



###Minimizer code:
def get_residual(params, x, y):
    Vmax = params['Vmax']
    Km = params['Km']
    model = Vmax * x / (Km + x)
    return model - y

#Parameters definition for LmFit
params = Parameters()
params.add('Vmax',value=4000., min=0)
params.add('Km',value=3., min=0)

#Produces the Km and Vmax value which is then extranted
minner = Minimizer(get_residual, params, fcn_args=(x,y))
result = minner.minimize()
print "Result of minization, deviation from y value:", result.residual

#Resulting in the final y-data, which gives the fitted data.
final = y + result.residual
print "I am here, Final:", final

#Gives report over the minimize function
print "Result.params:"
result.params.pretty_print()
print "Report_fit:"
report_fit(result)

#Transfer lmFit output of the minimize(result) to variable for further use
Vmax=result.params['Vmax'].value
Km=result.params['Km'].value
print "Fitted - Heres Km", Km
print "Fitted - Heres Vmax", Vmax

#Draw the different graphs
#plt.plot(x,fitfunc_michment(x, *popt),'b',label='curve_fit')
plt.plot(x,final,'r',label='lmfit')
plt.plot(x,model,'b',label='model')
plt.plot(x,y,'rs',label='Raw')
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=std, ecolor='r', linestyle="None")
plt.xlabel(s.join(['Concentration of ', subst ,' [', conc_unit,']']),fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Intensity [A.U.]', fontsize=12)
plt.savefig('Michaelis_Menten_plot.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
print 'Hello World, i am the Km value: ', Km
print 'Vmax value: ', Vmax
```

Hope you can help me!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to fit the model described in `my_model` to data y(x) (in the arrays `y` and `x`) and use the uncertainty in `y`, `std`, to weight the fit -- minimizing *(data - mode)/uncertainty* rather than just *data - model*.

To do this with `lmfit.Model`, you want to pass in a weight of `1./std` (probably checking for divde-by-zero), as with:

```
result = gmodel.fit(y, x=x, Vmax=4000.0, Km=3.0, weights=1.0/(std))
```

(it wasn't clear to me why there was both `std` and `std_1`.

To do this with `Minimize`, add `std` as to the `fcn_args` tuple (arguments to be passed to your objective function), and change the objective function to replace

```
return model - y
```

with

```
return (model -y)/std
```

With that, you should be ready to go.

FWIW, `Model.fit` uses `Minimizer`, so it's not really "less statistical", it's just a different emphasis.

As an aside, there are probably more efficient ways to load the data (perhaps some variation of `numpy.loadtxt`) but that's not the main question here.